# Struts2 Action messages for multiple fields with same name

Tags: struts2

How to Display the error message using Struts2 having same text box names.

```xml
<s:form action="../../multipleUserImage" method="POST"
        enctype="multipart/form-data"
        onsubmit="return Checkfiles(this);">     
   
    <span id="validationuploadfile" name="validationuploadfile" class="error" 
          style="color: red" ></span>

    <s:file label="Image 1" name="fileUpload" id="file1" size="40" cssClass="aa"/>
    <s:file label="Image 2" name="fileUpload"  id="file2" size="40" cssClass="aa"/>
    <s:file label="Image 3" name="fileUpload" id="file3" size="40" cssClass="aa"/>
    <s:file label="Image 4" name="fileUpload" id="file4" size="40" cssClass="aa"/>
    <s:file label="Image 5" name="fileUpload" id="file5" size="40" cssClass="aa"/>

    <s:submit value="Upload" name="submit"/>
</s:form>
```

This is the view code..
[image]

This is the error messages i got...................

[image]

I want to get the messages like this only

Comment: What do you mean like this? How many messages like this do you want to show if several fields have errors?

Comment: if i put the validation in server side error messages are shown like in the first image and if i change the name of the fileUpload input to other name like fileUpload1 the errors messages are displayed like in the second image but i want the error messages for the fileds with same name but displaying the error messages for specific  fileds

Comment: You should clarify *specific*, and you didn't _put the validation in server side_, didn't provide the code to do it on client side. So, I don't understand what do you want.

Comment: i applied the validations for checking the file upload size limit of 1mb for each filed with same name and with different ids.But if i applied the validations for file input components with the same name the errors messages are not showing only for the specific file input component it shows for all the fields because of file input components having the same name as fileUpload,So i want to display the error messages only for those fields having the validation errors...

Comment: Post the code how do you _apply the validations_.

Comment: <action name="multipleUserImage"
   class="com.serviceprovider.actions.UploadAllImagesAction">
   <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
   <param name="maximumSize">1024000</param>
   
      </interceptor-ref>
     
      <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
      <result name="success">/pages/serviceprovider/uploadsuccess.jsp</result>
      <result name="input">/pages/serviceprovider/allPictures.jsp</result>
  </action>

Comment: i want the ouput in the second image

Comment: Checkout `validate()` method and `<s:ActionError/>` tag.

Comment: By using <s:ActionError/> tag i will get the output in the first image